# Many to Many relation between two databases Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-database

I am building a separate Django project to handle a chat system, I already have a different Django project for everything else (user login info and serves API that does not relate to chat).

In this chat project, it has a model

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    rmid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And a database router:

```
class UserAuthRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'database_with_django_auth_models'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'database_with_django_auth_models'
        return None
```

This allows me to use the same user login info from the main project since I have connected the database in settings.

When I try to access `ChatRoom` model, I believe because the many-to-many field is relating to User model in the Auth lib/module, it causes this error as it is routed to use the other database:

```
Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, 
"Table 'database_with_django_auth_models.apps_chat_chatroom_people' doesn't exist")
```

But the `apps_chat_chatroom_people` datatable is in the database that contains the ChatRoom schema, (i.e. the second database that is going to be used for the chat system)

What is the proper way to handle this?
I want to be able to use the same login credentials.

Comment: I created a new model to replace the many-to-many field. This model will be on the chat system database. 
Room_People_Relation model where it has FK to User, and ChatRoom, and a timestamp field indicates join time.
There must be a better way to do this if anyone knows.
For the FK to Users, `db_constrains` must be false

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't support that feature [cross-database-relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations).

You can't use model relationships with models from different databases, you only can save the id or IDs and create your own code for obtain the data from another database.

Comment: I know it is not officially supported. But I suppose there is a workaround. I believe you can do FK between databases and set db_constrain=False. 

I feel like there gotta to be a way to do it.

Comment: The unique form that I know, is to save the ID number and create the own methods to look up data. You can overwrite the filter, all, etc method in the model manager. The `constrains=False` only removes the validation in the table and migrations, but the ORM tries to execute a query in a database with the field and the table doesn't exist, you should call that model with `values()` to get only specific fields and remove the join with another table in the query